# One hour Lufthansa transit time in Frankfurt from Bangalore to Dublin

Tags: transit, short-connections, lufthansa, fra

I have bought a ticket to travel from Bangalore (India) to Dublin (Ireland) via Frankfurt (Germany). Both of the flights is of Lufthansa and as a part of the same ticket. The transit time I will have in Frankfurt is 1 hour. Last time when I travelled in the same route, there was 1 hour and 20 minutes of time available between changing aircraft, but the connecting flight was late and I was able to board comfortably. Therefore I am not able to estimate this time how long it may take. I was wondering if this is too little time.

Also, I would like to know what the possibilities are in the case of missing the connecting flight?

Comment: Did you book your flights on the same ticket?

Comment: Yes on the same ticket. I did not book them separately.

Comment: To me it seems pretty "tight".  What time of day is it and which day of the week?  You can check if there are more flights on to Dublin, that day, after your flight. If you miss the flight it is "their fault" and they'll put you on the next one ... where a seat is available.

Comment: @MaxWyss That shouldn't have changed too much, as you note Dublin is still outside of Schengen. You could probably post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Check the average arrival time of first flight to see the actual connect you have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A One hour transfer should be enough at Frankfurt airport. Especially if your luggage is booked through, but even then it should be ok.

There are some hints and tips on the airport website.

[Frankfurt-airport.com](http://www.frankfurt-airport.com/content/frankfurt_airport/en/transfer/faqs-tips.html)

The printed guide (on page 7)

[static.fraport.de](http://static.fraport.de/ONLINE/Flippbook_trans/EN/pubData/mobile/index.htm#/7/)

Highlights the fact that you may have to pass through a security or passport checkpoint, and that there are fast lanes for short time connections. There are monitors showing which flights are allowed through the fast lane.

I would advise the flight crew when you board that you have a tight connection at the transfer airport, so they can make sure you are off the plane before the rest of the passengers.

Answer (score 10):

This has been a comment, but was suggested to become upgraded to an answer (I also took the freedom to rewrite it slightly)…

Back when I got through Frankfurt quite a bit, the minimal connection time was 45 minutes (from LH to LH flights). But that was before Schengen, and I stayed in the "international" section. As Ireland is not part of Schengen, this has not changed much, particularly that you don't have to pass immigration.

But if the connection is on one single ticket, it has been sanctioned by the system, and should be fine. If it does not work out (for example because of a late arrival), go to a Lufthansa counter which will get you rebooked. There may also be agents waiting at the gate to take care of you (for example rush you to the departure gate, if the delay is not too big), although I never encountered that because my short connections flights came in from the North Atlantic, and usually were early.